# Retrieving the format of an object of class 'Date' in R

Tags: r

Say I want to store *1 February, 2003* as a date using a *day-month-year without century* format and I do the following:

```
> date <- as.Date("01-02-03", format = "%d-%m-%y")
```

And then I forget what format that date was in, and do this:

```
> date
[1] "2003-02-01"
```

In order to determine if `01` is the month or the day, I can do this:

```
> format(date, "%d")
[1] "01"
```

But is there a way to directly retrieve the format this date was stored in?

Comment: R only stores dates `Date` objects in one format. And technically it's a numeric format. The value is only formatted to look like a date when you `print()` the value. There is no formatting stored with the Date object. Dates are always printed yyyy-mm-dd ISO style when using the default print method. You can change that by using `format()` or `strftime()`.

Comment: @MrFlick I believe what you wrote is accurate. You should copy it into an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Agreed; add a link to the reference and I'll accept it: https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/as.Date.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R only stores dates `Date` objects in one format. And technically it's a numeric format. The value is only formatted to look like a date when you `print()` the value. There is no formatting stored with the Date object. For example

```
dput(as.Date("2003-02-01"))
# structure(12084, class = "Date")
```

Dates are always printed yyyy-mm-dd ISO style when using the default print method. You can change that by using `format()` or `strftime()`. But the internal representation is always the same.