# Class character to date while maintaining the format

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have the dataframe below:

```
a <- c("2019-07-23 00:00", "2019-07-23 01:00", "2019-07-23 02:00")
b <- c(1,2,3)
bind <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I would like to make a date column for column bind$a, but when I do this with the code below, the format is changed. When I try to change the format, the column class goes back to character...

```
bind$a <- format(as.POSIXct(bind$a,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'),format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
bind$a <- as.Date(bind$a, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

How could I transform bind$a into a date column, while maintaining the format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'?
Thanks!

Comment: Possibly answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/74825279/4413615.

Comment: `format(.)` returns a string, not a `Date` object. Just use `as.POSIXct(bind$a, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` for a timestamp or `as.Date(bind$a, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` for a date object.